# Why is the implementation of access_ok macro from uaccess.h not using all of its arguments?

Tags: c, unix, macros, kernel, ioctl

The following code from /urs/src/linux-header-#version/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess.h is defining the macro access_ok with "type" as an argument. However, the definition of this macro is not using this argument anywhere.

```
#define access_ok(type, addr, size) (likely(__range_not_ok(addr, size) == 0))
```

Am I missing something? 
The "type" was supposed to have 2 possible values:
    #define VERIFY_READ 0
    #define VERIFY_WRITE 1

My only explanation is that this is for consistency. (On different platforms, "type" might be taken into the consideration in the implementation of access_ok).

Answer (score 2):

The fact that *this* implementation of the macro doesn't use it is an implementation detail. What `access_ok` *logically* does is given an answer in terms of all three parameters; it just happens that the answer for x86 (and most other platforms) doesn't actually need to take `type` into account. (On some of the platforms, the implementation doesn't take *any* arguments into account and just returns a 1. On others, e.g. [UML](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/um/include/asm/uaccess.h), `type` is indeed used.) `access_ok` is part of the abstracted API that should be consistent across platforms, and `type` is an attribute of the memory in Linux's abstracted model of it, so the parameter is necessary.

"Consistency" is kinda the right conclusion but reached from the wrong premise: the API is determined by the abstract, portable model of the system, a model which includes `type`. In this case it's the responsibility of the implementation to conform to the API, not of the API to bend to the details of the implementation.